# How to get the Value contained in ActionResult.Value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Our controller action is defined as:

```
public ActionResult<List<NoteModel>> GetNotesList(int ID)
```

in my test,

```
ActionResult<List<NoteModel>> result = Task.Run(() => controller.GetNotesList(123)).Result;
Assert.AreEqual(1, (result.Value.Count);
Assert.AreEqual(1, ((result.Result as OkObjectResult).Value as List<NoteModel>).Count);
```

The first assert compiles without a cast because it "knows" that the value is a list of notes. But the assert fails because the value is null at runtime.

The second assert passes because it contains the actual list, but it doesn't "know" that it is a list, so I have to cast it.

Seems like that can't be the right/expected way to do this and I must be doing something wrong.

---

UPDATE
We took a stab at making it async, like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<NoteModel>>> GetNotesList(int ID)
```

and updated the test code to

```
ActionResult<List<NoteModel>> result = await controller.GetNotesList(123);
Assert.AreEqual(1, (result.Value.Count);
```

result.Value is List as it should be, but still null.

---

UPDATE 2
Inspecting the OkObjectResult *before* it is returned by the controller, and the Value is properly typed AND set.

So I think what is happening is that my return type, ActionResult<List>, and my return, OkObjectResult(list) don't match up.

I'm getting an ActionResult, but no value, because I'm not returning a value.  When I just returned a value

```
 return list;
```

this worked.  But I also want to return a proper status code, which was failing.

I want an ActionCode that has a Value and a StatusCode. How do I return both?

---

CODE

```
----- NoteModel.cs -----
namespace SampleAPI.Models {

    public class NoteModel {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
----- NotesController.cs -----
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SampleAPI.Models;

namespace SampleAPI.Controllers {
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NotesController: ControllerBase {

        public NotesController() {
        }

        // Read notes API
        // GET: api/Notes/Read/{NoteID}
        [HttpGet("ReadNote1")]
        public ActionResult<NoteModel> ReadNoteReturnsOK() {
            try {
                NoteModel note = new NoteModel() { Title = "GetStarted" };
                return Ok(note);
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }

        // Read notes API
        // GET: api/Notes/Read/{NoteID}
        [HttpGet("ReadNote2/{NoteID}")]
        public ActionResult<NoteModel> ReadNoteReturnsValue() {
            try {
                NoteModel note = new NoteModel() { Title = "GetStarted" };
                return note;
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
}
----- NotesControllerTest.cs -----
using NUnit.Framework;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using SampleAPI.Controllers;
using SampleAPI.Models;
#pragma warning disable NUnit2005 // Consider using Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected)) instead of Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
#pragma warning disable NUnit2006 // Consider using Assert.That(actual, Is.Not.EqualTo(expected)) instead of Assert.AreNotEqual(expected, actual)

namespace SampleTest.Controllers {
    public class NotesControllerTest {
        private NotesController controller;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup() {
            controller = new NotesController();
        }


        [Test]
        public void ReadNoteGoodResult1() {
            // Arrange            

            // Act
            ActionResult<NoteModel> result = Task.Run(() => controller.ReadNoteReturnsOK()).Result;

            //Verify          
            Assert.NotNull(result);

#pragma warning disable CS8602 // We know that result is not null, so we can ignore this warning.
            // This is what we don't want to do.
            Assert.AreEqual("GetStarted", ((result.Result as OkObjectResult).Value as NoteModel).Title); 
            Assert.AreEqual(StatusCodes.Status200OK, (result.Result as IStatusCodeActionResult).StatusCode);
            // This is what we want, but it fails.
            Assert.AreEqual("GetStarted", result.Value.Title); // compiles but fails because Value is null
#pragma warning restore CS8602 // Dereference of a possibly null reference.
        }

        [Test]
        public void ReadNoteGoodResult2() {
            // Arrange            

            // Act
            ActionResult<NoteModel> result = Task.Run(() => controller.ReadNoteReturnsValue()).Result;

            //Verify          
            Assert.NotNull(result);

#pragma warning disable CS8602 // We know that result is not null, so we can ignore this warning.
            // This is what we want, and Hey, it works!
            Assert.AreEqual("GetStarted", result.Value.Title); // Value is populated
            // Status code is AWOL because result.Result is null.
            Assert.AreEqual(StatusCodes.Status200OK, (result.Result as IStatusCodeActionResult).StatusCode);
#pragma warning restore CS8602 // Dereference of a possibly null reference.
        }
    }
}
--------------
```

Download the [sample project zip file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/xs4r52h741csy8gutx3i9/SampleProject.zip?rlkey=3virap3879j8v11mm8ww0sf0q&dl=0).

Comment: Update your action method to use **async** and **Task**. Also update your test method to be **async** and **await** the controller action. This should fix your issues.

Comment: @AztecCodes  Either I didn't do it right or it didn't help.

Comment: Can you please add a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `OkObjectResult` via `Ok()` method so you need to access the value via it, as you do in the first part of the test:

```
Assert.AreEqual("GetStarted", ((result.Result as OkObjectResult).Value as NoteModel).Title);
```

From the [`ActionResult<TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0) docs:

> A type that wraps either an `TValue` instance or an `ActionResult`.

So `return Ok(...)` is exactly second case, since `ActionResult` -> `ObjectResult` -> `OkObjectResult` hierarchy.

The `ActionResult<TValue>.Value` approach will work if you will change the controller to:

```
try 
{
    NoteModel note = new NoteModel() { Title = "GetStarted" };
    return note;
}
```

In this case `result.Value` will not be null.

Comment: Yes. As I think my code demonstrated in Method1 and Method2. The question remains, how do I return a value and a 200 status code? Do people just not return a status code if there is a value? Why not?

Comment: @BWhite both `return Ok(note)` and `return note` should result in 200 with value.

Comment: Can you suggest some code to retrieve the status code? In my code, result doesn't have a status code, as it isn't a relative of ActionResult. result.Result *is* an ActionResult, so it would have a status code, except that it is null, so it doesn't.

Comment: For example, this code: Assert.AreEqual(StatusCodes.Status200OK, (result.Result as IStatusCodeActionResult).StatusCode); fails because result.Result is null.

Comment: @BWhite write the integration test and analyze the response.

Comment: Interesting. We don't currently have any integration tests on this project but we were just talking about adding them. I'll move that up on the list.     8: -)